# PHP - How to format data for in_array

Tags: php, mysql

I have comma separated numbers in `1` database field (1,2,58,65) and want to check if `$_SESSION['customer_id']` is in array, but don't know how to format `$adminids` to get it work. It works with 1 number, but not with more than 1. I already tried other methods than in_array, but I always fail.

This is my code.

```
$lsc_adminid_query = xtDBquery("SELECT lsc.option_id,
                            lsc.option_value 
                            FROM lsc_config lsc
                            WHERE lsc.option_id = 27");

while ($adminid_query = xtc_db_fetch_array($lsc_adminid_query)) {
    if (xtc_not_null($adminid_query['option_value'])) {
        $adminids = $adminid_query['option_value'];
    }
}
$lsc_cid = array($adminids);

if (in_array($_SESSION['customer_id'], $lsc_cid)) {
    $lsc_admin = "lsc_admin";
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$lsc_admin])) {
        setcookie($lsc_admin, '1', time() + (7200), "/");
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that `lsc.option_value` can be (for example) 1,12,86?  And you want to check if `$_SESSION['customer_id']` is in the list?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: You are right! But why you ask for which database I use? Database MySQL

Comment: This is not a duplicate and @Barmar is wrong.

Comment: Why isn't it a duplicate? Use `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(27, lsc.option_id)`

Comment: You're overwriting the `$adminids` variable each time through the `while` loop. You should push them into the array in the loop.

Comment: I would have thought more `WHERE lsc.option_id = 27 and FIND_IN_SET(?, lsc.option_value)` where ? is the parameter for `$_SESSION['customer_id']`.

Comment: @NigelRen Yeah, I was confused about which column is the comma-separated list.

Comment: I have many comma separated numbers in 1 field and not 1 per row. lsc.option_id doesn't matter for my function und will be removed. It's all about lsc_option_value == numbers to check.

Comment: So use `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, lsc.option_value)`

Comment: @Barmar Would you please extend your suggestion code? I am not a full stack developer, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FIND_IN_SET()` to search for an element of a comma-separated list.

```
$lsc_adminid_query = xtDBquery("
    SELECT lsc.option_id
    FROM lsc_config lsc
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET({$_SESSION['customer_id']}, lsc.option_value)");
```

But it would be better to normalize your design so you don't have comma-separated lists in database columns in the first place.

Comment: Your code works!  Thank you! What do you mean with "normalize your design"? Other delimiter or only spaces?

Comment: Okay, this design is better!

Comment: Here is the next challenge for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603835/php-how-to-format-list-of-uris-in-an-array-to-fill-other-array